# Trouble in draw stacked column chart in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have to draw a stacked column chart in a php web. The chart must has lines connect assosiated stacks in itself, and that is the important thing I don't have solution for. The chart look like [this](http://image.tutorvista.com/content/feed/u773/4_14.GIF)

Do you have any ideas to draw this? I precious you helping so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out https://developers.google.com/chart/ or YUI Charts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [d3.js](http://d3js.org) for these kind of visualizations. This is a pure JavaScript library which you could use easily. Take a look at this and update for yourself as you wish: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Or a list of available charts: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery